# Android studio stopped giving me hints

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I don't know when it started but at some point android studio stopped giving me hints for some of my widgets. Like in the picture, before he suggested writing "android: id"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKIxd.png)

I tried to write a few things on my old projects and everything works there, I can't figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: This question definitely doesn't share enough information for us to answer. If it's working on old projects, try this: does it work on a brand new project? If not, compare the configuration files between an old and new project (I believe they are found inside the `.idea` folder of each project). What's different?

Answer (score 0):

looks like your textview already has an id
else try to invalidate and restart
else Settings(Preferences on Mac) -> Editor -> Code completion

Comment: I tried, nothing has changed. I asked a few more programmers, they said that they have the same thing, maybe this AndroidStudio is not working properly

Comment: @RamzabShikarno try to type something like this android:id="@+id/tvName"